# How to convert ASCII value to UTF-8 String in Java? 9812 -> ♔

Tags: java

I want to convert the asci value of `9812` to [♔](https://www.utf8icons.com/character/9812/white-chess-king) UTF-8 `string`. How can it be done?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  Strings in Java are never stored in UTF-8, only in (slightly modified) UTF-16.  Also, 9812 is not an ASCII value.  Are you saying you want to convert that number to the String that it represents in UTF-16?

Comment: `9812` is not an ASCII value, [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) being limited to 128 numbers. [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: @BasilBourque yeah agree. I just followed the definition on the linked site.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking of sending a comment in to the people who run that site.  It's really misleading, especially considering that many of the people who use that site will be people who don't have their heads around all of this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a character in char range, then it's just:

```
Character.toString(9812).getBytes("UTF8")
```

If it's a code point larger than U+00FFFF, then you can use:

```
new String(Character.toChars(0x10400)).getBytes("UTF8")
```

If you just want a `String`, not the byte array with the UTF-8 representation, then omit `getBytes`.

Comment: Tnx. You only forgot the char casting in the toString call.

Comment: Your first approach seems to succeed with a code point over U+00FFFF. See [this code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/ViJh2f) using "Face with Tears of Joy" character at code point 128,514 to produce the same byte array `[-16, -97, -104, -126]` using both of your two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Character.toString`:

```java
String myString = Character.toString(9812);
```

Alternatively, if you only need a char, then you don't need any functions:

```java
char myChar = 9812;
```

Comment: The `char` type is obsolete, unable to handle even half of the characters defined in Unicode.

Comment: @BasilBourque it is not obsolete. It represents UTF-16 nodes; usually, entire symbols; sometimes, one half of a surrogate pair. This is baked into the Unicode spec (0xD800-0xDFFF are intentionally 'left blank', in perpetuity, in order for 'char' to continue to work fine).

Answer (score -1):

The number 9812 in decimal is 2654 in Hexadecimal. There is an Open source library that can convert any string into Unicode sequence and vice-versa. So the following code will print your desired String.

```
System.out.println(StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString("\\u2654"));
```

The output would be:

```
♔
```

Converting String to Unicode sequences would be as follows:

```
System.out.println(StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("Hello World"));
```

would result in this output:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
```

The library is called MgntUtils and could be found as Maven artifact [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) and at Github including jar, source code and Javadoc [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases). Just Javadoc for class `StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder` can be found [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)